# phonegap android local notification cancelAll not working

Tags: android, cordova, localnotification

hi I am using phonegap local notification plugin in my android project.
notification are working great. 
i can delete a notification with ID 
but in my app i have to delete all notification option, for which this plugin gives a method to cancelAll notification.
which is:-

```
    plugins.localNotification.cancelAll();
```

but this is not working.
i am using this plugin from here
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be the answer to this one. As it says in the description of the `cancelAllNotifications()` method (LocalNotification.java line 124):

> Android can only unregister a specific alarm. There is no such thing as cancelAll. Therefore **we rely on the Shared Preferences** which holds all our alarms to loop through these alarms and unregister them one by one.

However, take a look at the code where the `cancelAllNotifications()` method is called (line 59):

```
} else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("cancelall")) {
    unpersistAlarmAll();
    return this.cancelAllNotifications();
}
```

Here's what `unpersistAlarmAll()` looks like (line 181):

```
private boolean unpersistAlarmAll() {
final Editor alarmSettingsEditor = this.cordova.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PLUGIN_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

alarmSettingsEditor.clear();

return alarmSettingsEditor.commit();
}
```

What's happening is that the alarmIds are being cleared from sharedPreferences **before** `cancelAllNotifications()` is called, effectively leaving no alarms to be canceled.

I'm not sure where the best place to move the call to `unpersistAlarmAll()` is, and I'd be happy to get some suggestions. In the meantime I have moved it to within `cancelAllNotifications()`, after the result returned from `alarm.cancelAll(alarmSettings)` is tested (line 133), like so:

```
if (result) {
    unpersistAlarmAll();
    return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
```

So far this seems to be working fine. Perhaps another way to do this would be to scrap the whole `unpersistAlarmAll()` method and instead call `unpersistAlarm(String alarmId)` (line 168) after each individual alarm is successfully canceled.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do, you could use the "Statusbar notificaiton". This plugin will enable you to put message on the android status bar.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification

Comment: thanks for the answer bond, actually I need to schedule notification on calendar with an option to delete them ..